# Woocommerce Send only email admin if specific product is on the cart

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want that if there is a specific item in the cart (via id), only the notification email is sent to the admin and not to the customer

Is there a snippet that allows me to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in your theme's functions.php file. Don't forget to replace the email with your own.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'cwpai_woo_send_email_to_admin_on_add_to_cart', 10, 6 );
function cwpai_woo_send_email_to_admin_on_add_to_cart( $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data ) {
    $product      = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    $product_name = $product->get_name();
    $user         = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_name    = $user->user_login;
    $time         = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );

    $message = sprintf(
        '%s was added to the cart by %s at %s',
        $product_name,
        $user_name,
        $time
    );

    wp_mail( 'admin@example.com', 'Product added to cart', $message );
}
```